# Passing Value from RouterStateSnapshot to my Root Routing File in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to figure out how to pass the value from the RouterStateSnapshot in my auth.guard file to my routing file in my Angular 2 app. I want to do this because, rather than loading a hard-coded default component first, I want, after re-login, for the last active component/page to load up. I have this value in my canActivate() function in my AuthGuard file, because I can console out it out via RouterStateSnapshot. So now I need to figure out how to pass this value on to my root routing file so it, on login/re-login, that component gets loaded.

This is the `canActivate()` function in my `AuthGuard` file:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
{
    // Get route content id
    let contentId = Object.getPropertyValueAtPath(route, 'data.contentId');

    console.log(state.url);

    // If route does not have session id, don’t load in tab view
    if (!String.isNotNullOrEmpty(contentId))
    {
        console.error(`Route (${route.routeConfig.path}) does not have a content id.`);
        this.router.navigateByUrl(''); // Forward to default page.
        this.router.navigate([state.url]);
        return false;
    }

    if (this.disabled) return true;

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
    {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login', {returnUrl: state.url}]);
    return false;
}
```

Notice that I am doing this within that function: `console.log(state.url)`. This gives me the correct value. Now I need to pass it to my app-routing file.

To clarify, currently, on re-login, the last active component *is* loaded -- but it displays as a background tab, and the default 'redirect' component is what loads up as the active component (i.e, it shows as the active tab).

A simplified version of the app-routing file looks like this:

```
import { HomeComponent } ...

export const routes: Routes = [

{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },

{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }

];
```

As you can see above, on initial load I currently redirect the user to the 'home component' by default. What I'd like to do is re-direct them to the value that is stored in "state.url" from RouterStateSnapshot. I'm not clear how to do this, however. Any ideas as to how I'd pass that value from my AuthGuard file down to my app-routing file? Can I simply inject RouterStateSnapshot into my app-routing file to get that desired value directly? Or can I use "resolve" here along with the path in routing? What's the recommended way to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplish this by storing the url in a shared service from my AuthGuard

```
// auth-guard.ts
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  let isLoggedIn = this.authService.isUserLoggedIn();

  if(isLoggedIn){
    return true;
  }else{
    this.someService.storeRedirectUrl(state.url);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then when the user logs in, check if that redirect url was stored and navigate to it

```
// login method within login page
login(){
  this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe(
    res => {
      // successful user login, so determine where to route user
      if(this.someService.redirectUrl){
        // redirect url found, navigate to that url
        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.someService.redirectUrl);
      }else{
        // if no redirect url found, navigate to normal landing page
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      }
  });
}
```

Routes File

```
// routes
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: 'about', 
    component: AboutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: 'home' 
  }
];
```

---

> Can I simply inject RouterStateSnapshot into my app-routing file to get that desired value directly?

app-routing is just for mapping routes to components, so there is no injecting the route snapshot into it.

Another option you could do is to pass the redirect url as a query parameter of the login page within the auth guard. (I think this was what you were heading towards)

```
// auth-guard.ts
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  let isLoggedIn = this.authService.isUserLoggedIn();

  if(isLoggedIn){
    return true;
  }else{
    this.router.navigate(['/login', {redirectUrl: state.url}]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then the process is the same after a user logs in successfully, except this time you fetch the redirect url from the url parameters instead of the service.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Regarding your last point, I actually am doing exactly that if you look at my code. I have this within my canActivate function:

this.router.navigate(['/login', {returnUrl: state.url}]);

However, while that state.url does re-load on login -- it's not the active tab. The active tab is defined the re-direct in my routing file:
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: 'home' 

So the question is, how do I not only load components from before logout, but actually navigate to that as the active tab/component?

Comment: I do think the shared service may be the best way to go here. Will try implementing that now.

Comment: @Muirik hmm I think I am confused on what you mean by the active tab/component. Can you give an example of the the routing path you are talking about in your example? (user navigates to `/about`, user is not logged in so user is kicked to `/login`, user logs in and is redirected to `/home`? `/about`?)

Comment: After successful re-login the user is re-directed to Home - because of the routing file re-direct. Now, if a user had several components open before being logged out (these are represented like page tabs in our app), then, when they log BACK in, all of those tabs will load up -- because the state was captured in ActivatedRouteSnapshot. However --- and this is the key -- the active component (in the foreground) will be "Home" - because of the re-direct logic in the routing file. What I want instead is to make the last active component the active comp AGAIN after successfully re-logging in.

Comment: @Muirik what is the url that you are trying to navigate to after re-login? It sounds like the active tab/component state isn't stored in the url

Comment: As I mentioned above, in my canActivate() function (see above) I'm doing this: console.log(state.url); This logs to the console the correct url to load on re-login. So the value is available, it's just a matter of figuring out how to pass it in correctly so that it's not being overridden by the re-direct defined in the routing file.

Comment: @Muirik right. It's odd that it is hitting the `redirectTo`. That means whatever route you are navigating to does not match any of your route definitions

Comment: Interesting point. Just thinking about that. Going to try removing the redirect and see what happens.